# Change the font size of matplotlib.pyplot Axis after its been set

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How to change the font size of the X-Axis or Y-Axis on a matplotlib.pyplot plot in Python.

I'm want to change the fon size of the text that has already set and I don't want to re-enter the text. Is it possible to get the axis object and set its font size ?

Answer (score 0):

To change the font size of the x-axis tick labels or y-axis tick labels in a Matplotlib plot, you can use the `tick_params` function and set the `labelsize` parameter.

Here is an example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some data to plot
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 4, 6, 8, 10]

# Create a figure and a subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the data
ax.plot(x, y)

# Set the font size of the x-axis and y-axis tick labels
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=20)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=20)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Also if you didn't stored the `fig, ax` objects you can reach them with `plt.gca()`

Here is an example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some data to plot
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 4, 6, 8, 10]

# Create a figure and a subplot
plt.figure()

# Plot the data
plt.plot(x, y)

# Set the font size of the x-axis and y-axis tick labels
plt.gca().xaxis.label.set_size(20)
plt.gca().yaxis.label.set_size(20)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```